# How many rolls required to have three consecutive any number

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

Hi Need Help to solve this problem

How many rolls required for a dice to get any number consecutively $3$ times? for example $111, 222, 333$ ??

I've seen some formula, but most of them looking for certain number instead of any.

please show me the logical structure step by step, so I could understand clearly.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "How many rolls are necessary?"  It may never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want the *expected* number of rolls.

An easy approach is via recursion.

For $k\in\{0,1,2\}$, let $e_k$ be the expected number of rolls to get three consecutive equal values, assuming $k$ is the length of the maximum block of immediately preceding rolls with equal values.

Then we have the system
\begin{align*}
e_0&=1+e_1\\[4pt]
e_1&=1+{\small{\frac{5}{6}}}e_1+{\small{\frac{1}{6}}}e_2\\[4pt]
e_2&=1+{\small{\frac{5}{6}}}e_1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
of $3$ linear equations in $3$ unknowns.

Solving the system yields $e_0=43$.

To explain the recursion . . .

- The initial roll yields $k=1$ (i.e., $1$ is the length of the maximum block of immediately preceding rolls with equal values).

  After the initial roll, if a roll matches the prior roll, $k$ is incremented by $1$, else $k$ is reset to $1$.

  For each equation, the added constant $1$ on the $\text{RHS}$ counts the roll that just occurred.